# Filler Material

Tags: materials, strength

If I was to add a filler to a metallic substance, is it possible for the Young's modulus to decrease as filler content increases?

Also, when a filler is added, how do the atoms change for improving strength please? Do they just prevent motion?

Comment: sure, if the filler is bonded to the item, and if the filler has a different modulus.  I have no idea what you mean about atoms.

Comment: Hi, thanks. For the atoms, what happens at an atomic level when filler material is added to a sample please?

Comment: nothing happens, this is a macro-level process.  Each material will behave as itself.

Comment: Sure, for example with AlSiC metal matrix composite (ie not a proper alloy), by varying the ratio of aluminum to silicon carbide, you can tune the modulus over a meaningful range.  (alternatively the thermal expansion is often the parameter being tuned). Technically SiC is a non metal and it increases modulus but hopefully close enough conceptually.